# how to remove certain columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am just starting with python and pandas. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
1  2.3  1  2.5  1  4.5
2  2.3  2  2.5  2  4.5
3  2.3  3  2.5  3  4.5
4  2.3  4  2.5  4  4.5
5  2.3  5  2.5  5  4.5
```

I am trying to remove all the identical columns except for the first one so I want to be left with:

```
1  2.3  2.5  4.5
2  2.3  2.5  4.5
3  2.3  2.5  4.5
4  2.3  2.5  4.5
5  2.3  2.5  4.5
```

I have managed to obtain the indices of the identical columns in a list `duplicate_cols`.
`duplicate_cols=[2,4] in the example above.

But when I try to extract them from the dataframe with:

```
dataframe.drop(dataframe.columns[duplicate_cols], axis=1)
```

All the columns are removed (the ones with `1 2 3 4 5` I mean). I was expecting the first column to stay (by that I mean column 0).

Can anyone tell me where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe I understand it wrong, but your two dataframes (input and expected output) are identical.

Comment: can you please show us how the output should look like? it is the same as the one you are trying to change

Comment: sorry my bad! it was late and I was seeing double! I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this dataframe, and (by the description of your problem) that you want to remove cols 2 and 4 because they are duplicates of column 0:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1   2.3     1   2.5     1   4.5
1     2   2.3     2   2.5     2   4.5
2     3   2.3     3   2.5     3   4.5
3     4   2.3     4   2.5     4   4.5
4     5   2.3     5   2.5     5   4.5
```

You can use `drop_duplicates` on the transposed dataframe:

```
df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

Which will result in:

```
   col0  col1  col3  col5
0   1.0   2.3   2.5   4.5
1   2.0   2.3   2.5   4.5
2   3.0   2.3   2.5   4.5
3   4.0   2.3   2.5   4.5
4   5.0   2.3   2.5   4.5
```

Comment: fantastic! this is the answer I was looking for! thank you! But can you tell me if you don't mind, what was I doing wrong? I admit I tried to get answers from windows copilot last night and `df.drop` seemed like the solution. In the documentation I didn't see a mention that it drops everything. In my mind, it should work in conjunction with `df.columns` because you give it a list of specific columns to drop. And while that list is `[2,4]` it goes ahead and it also drops column `0` for some reason. I would like to understand so I can avoid this in the future!

Comment: @lucian There's nothing inherently wrong with your approach, but finding the indices of the duplicated columns takes more work, that's why I suggested a different approach. Maybe (i) you're using a different dataframe from the one you posted (unlikely if my solution worked for you) or (ii) when identifying duplicates, you're including index `0`.

Comment: If you index the columns directly it works fine: `df = df.drop(df.columns[[2, 4]], axis=1)`; or by column name: `df = df.drop(["col2", "col4"], axis=1)`.